# Is it safe to comment out the "@Override"?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-contacts, android-activity

To get my code to compile - which contained the following:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    Cursor mContacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Return all contacts, ordered by name
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        mContacts = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        // Display all contacts in a ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mContacts,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Listen for item selections
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
. . .
```

...I had to comment out the "@Override" above the onItemClick() event handler. Is this safe? Should I just shrug my shoulders and say, "OK, that works, I'll forget about it" or is there evil afoot/a hidden problem lurking?

Comment: You are hiding the true issue. Please post the problem you are getting and the complete method code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per my suggestion, it is not good to remove that line. you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors.  Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.

Answer (score 4):

If you had to comment out the `@Override`, then your compiler's JDK compliance level isn't set to 1.6, which it should be for Android development. If you're using Eclipse, right click on the project name and select "Properties". Then select "Java Compiler" and adjust as necessary. (You probably inherited a lower JDK compliance level from the workspace. If appropriate, change the compliance level for the workspace instead. This will save having to fix the same problem with new projects.)

But to answer your question: it's safe to comment out `@Override`. It's just not so great to be using a lower compliance level.

Answer (score 3):

You java version is set to less than 1.6. Starting there, interfaces and not just methods can be market as Override. Right click the project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level to 1.6

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html):

> `@Override` - the `@Override` annotation informs the compiler that the
>   element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass
>   (overriding methods will be discussed in the the lesson titled
>   "Interfaces and Inheritance").

```
   // mark method as a superclass method
   // that has been overridden
   @Override 
   int overriddenMethod() { }
```

> **While it's not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with @Override
>   fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the
>   compiler generates an error.**

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If your compiler is set to target java 5, and the onCreate method is inherited from the interface then yes.  Java 5 doesn't support the override annotation on interface methods, whereas Java 6 expects it.  This may itself be an indication that your JDK is set up wrong, if you're expecting to target Java 6, what you may be getting is Java 5.

Answer (score -1):

if you'd commented it out, you would not override the methods. So you'd actually do nothing. (My opinion)

Comment: The `@Override` doesn't affect whether methods are overridden or not. From the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html): _"While it's not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with_ `@Override` _fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error."_